# Table out of context

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I have a web page in which's content I have two tables, two menus. Now the tables are formatted the same, I simply copied the html of the first to the second, but still, the second doesn't seem to respect the width of my content div the way the first one does, why would this be? How can I get it to expand o 100% but stay within the ContentWrapper div?
link: http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/content/lunch

Comment: see my answer, it would help you since I have checked your site this is only thing making table to extend to much wide.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question itself. Links are not enough, especially links to live pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `width` of two table inside the second copy of your table with `1553px`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(234, 220, 213) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%); border-collapse:collapse; border:none; width:1553px">
```

Just remove it and you are sorted

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your first `td` element, you explicitly set your element's `style` attribute to `style="width:50%"`. You didn't do that in the second one.

```
<!-- first -->
<td class="rtecenter" colspan="2" style="width:50%">...</td>

<!-- second -->
<td>...</td>
```